# Typescript baseUrl not working in React Typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint-config-airbnb

I defined the `baseUrl` in my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"baseUrl": "src",
```

In `.eslintrc.js` I have:

```
parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: './tsconfig.json',
  },
```

Now in e.g. `index.tsx` I can import my components like `import Layout from 'components/layout';`

When I run `gatsby develop` I get some errors like:

```
If you're trying to use a package make sure that 'components/layout' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.
error undefined failed
```

What's missing here, why it isn't finding my components?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `import/resolver` settings in your `.eslintrc.js` so Webpack can identify `imports` of your components (I'm supposing that they have `.tsx` extension)

```js
settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        paths: [
          'src'
        ],
        extensions: [
          '.ts',
          '.tsx'
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: thanks, I am still getting the error. Do I also have to add the nom package `eslint-import-resolver-typescript`?

Comment: Actually, since you're using Gatsby, you can use some plugin like [this](https://github.com/alampros/gatsby-plugin-resolve-src). I think it would be way more easier to configure

Comment: before I look at the other plugin, do I have to install `eslint-import-resolver-typescript` to use above settings `import/resolver` in `.eslintrc.js`?

Comment: DId not work for me sadly!